# COM+ automatic collection of a process dump file and process termination at high call time

Tags: windows-server-2003, com+

hI,

I want to configure my machine for automatic collection of a process dump file and process termination as mentioned in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910904.

But after setting the registry settings according to the KB article, i am not getting the required behaviour. Only a warning is being logged when call time goes high (which is the default behaviour).

i am running Windows Server 2003 with SP2.

Is there any thing that i am missing? for example restart any COM+ runtime etc.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the folder: %systemroot%\system32\com\dmp\?

If you have not created this, you may want to, and grant full control to authenticated users.

Comment: dump folder exists. and my account has administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the path is correct in the Image Dump Directory box.  Make sure your server is running service pack 2.  Restart The Com+ Application